# Error on Android Studio code in class doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently developping an android app with Android Studio and until now everything was fine. However, when I opened my project this morning I find out that my code, written in Java, was gone replaced with some random xml code, for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="AndroidConfiguredLogFilters">
    <filters>
      <filter>
        <option name="logLevel" value="verbose" />
        <option name="logMessagePattern" value="" />
        <option name="logTagPattern" value="" />
        <option name="name" value="" />
        <option name="packageNamePattern" value="com.." />
        <option name="pid" value="" />
      </filter>
    </filters>
  </component>
```

Therefore, I tried to open my code with Notepad and everything was fine. Then, I uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio, but it was still the same. So, I removed the .idea folder and the .iml files, but nothing happened.
I am wondering if someone has ever experienced this issue and if someone could help me to solve this issue because for now I can't code with Android Studio.

Comment: Try Invalidate Cache and Restart option. Goto File(in the top-left-most corner) -> invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Yes I didn't mention it but I already did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally success to solve my issue.
I had to delete .AndroidStudio3.2 in the User file.